# Turtle files data processing from s3 to Neptune

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune

I have copied turtle files from s3 to Neptune through `curl post` method commands as suggested in the AWS document. `curl` command executed and job is successfully completed. Post job execution, I have checked the job id status to know the details of load status; my job showing overall status completed but record count is zero records. My turtle files in S3 have lots of records. Why did my `curl post` method not transfer a single record from S3 to Neptune? Please someone help if you have successfully moved turtle files from S3 to Neptune.

Comment: Hi. Could you post the full response from status API for this load request? You can also use the details flag to show more details on files processed etc., https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-status.html

Comment: From the document I have checked the loader status with job id and results showing as load_completed and no of records =0  , duplicate records =0  , totaltimespent =0

Comment: @Srinivas Do you need any other assistance on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks very specific to the kind of data you were loading. Opening a support case with Amazon Neptune or posting on AWS Forums with more details (sample requests and responses) might be a better option.

A few possibilities are:

1. Your turtle dataset has some issues. The [load status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-status.html) API should be able to help you with this.
2. This is a duplicate load request, and all the records ended up being marked as duplicates.

Comment: Below is the response I got from the loader API : status : 200 ok , payload : { feedcount : [ { LOAD_COMPLETED } ] , overall status : { fulluri : mybucket path  , status : load_completed , totalrecords  = 0 , totalduplicates = 0 , totaltimespend =0 , runnumber = 3 , retrynumber = 1,  insert errors =0 , parsingerrors =0 } , ....}

Comment: My best guess is that the file path specified to loader is incorrect so it is not finding any files in specified location. If that's not the case, please do a open a support case with Neptune.